# Problem of transistor thermal runaway in parallel connection

Tags: transistors, parallel, small-signal, transistor-array

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fJA7dl.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I wanted to use two transistors in parallel to increase current rating.
So I simply put two transistors in PCB design. Later I found thermal runaway in transistor which will create problem in parallel. For which general solution I find is to use resistor in emitter. But I didn't put it in design.

So is there any other way to solve this problem except to use resistor at emitter?

I search for it and found that using a shared heat sink will keep both transistor temperature same so current will increase in both together and current will be shared equally. Is it right ?

I also want to turn on transistor only for 3 seconds. So does I even need any solution for this or I can go without any solution as no constant current is flowing for long time?

Comment: Show your schematic. Show all power rails/ground and load and, add data sheet links to the important components.

Comment: Added Schematic. Transistors used are 2n2907 with rated current 600mA. My circuit draw nearly 450 to 500 mA from input supply. I just want to use 2 transistor for safe side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> So is there any other way to solve this problem except to use resistor at emitter?

Use a higher current transistor. Preferably PFET, but a larger BJT will do.

> I search for it and found that using a shared heat sink will keep both transistor temperature same so current will increase in both together and current will be shared equally. Is it right ?

No, it is too slow. The silicon chip in the transistor heats quite quickly, which decreases its threshold voltage and increases current, which causes thermal runaway in a much shorter time than it would take for the temperature to equalize through the heat sink.

> I also want to turn on transistor only for 3 seconds. So does I even need any solution for this or I can go without any solution as no constant current is flowing for long time?

If it is only for 3 seconds you could even use a NMOS driven with a voltage doubler, but that's a bit more circuit.

Simplest would be a PNP BJT rated for higher current and lower VceSAT. Preferably in a TO220 package or similar, that has enough thermal mass to soak up the hear for 3 seconds without needing a heat sink. Not a darlington, because you have low supply voltage so the very high VceSAT of a darlington would be a problem. But you can use a high current transistor and a separate driving transistor as a darlington, with collector to ground, that won't increase the VceSAT.

Answer (score 2):

If it is acceptable in your application, you can add resistors in series with the transistors on the emitter pin.

The transistor that carries the higher current will see a Vbe decrease because of the additional current flowing in the emitter resistor, therefore the runaway effect will tend to balance out.

The drawback of this approach is that you have additional power dissipated in the emitter resistors, but with 500 mA for 3 seconds, as you mention in the post, I am guessing that is not a big problem.

I also see that you mention that you cannot find a suitable FET for this application, but perhaps you can find a bigger BJT rated for higher currents, that make you feel a bit safer. It might even be possible for you to switch to an N device and put it on the ground side of the boost converter, but that depends on a number of different things.

If the rationale here is that you have some 2N2907 in the drawer and you want to use them, then I suggest the emitter resistors.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, use mosfets instead since they have positive temperature coefficient, they will balance out.

It can help to add a small resistor to the emitter to balance small vgs differences.

Look at mosfet based audio amplifier design.

Comment: I'm not sure, but don't MOSFETs only have positive tempco in saturation, but not in the linear region?

Comment: Also linear range

Comment: Thank you for suggestion. Yes, MOSFETs are better for parallel. Unfortunately MOSFET that switch at 3.3volts are not available in our local market. In next update I am going to switch over MOSFET if possible. But currently I have to work around with transistors only.

Comment: @Damien I believe mosfets have negative tempco in the sub-threshold range and crossover into positive tempco as Vgs magnitude increases.

Comment: @mkeith it's the other way around https://www.onsemi.com/pub/Collateral/AND8199-D.PDF

Comment: @Damien here is a quote "All  three  devices  shown  have  one  thing  in  common:a point of inflection at which the temperature coefficient is zero. At greater gate-to-source voltages, the coefficient is positive, and, at lower gate-to-source voltages it is negative." Not clear from the article whether the negative tempco is in the subthreshold region or not like I said. But it is negative below the crossover and positive above.

Comment: @mkeith there are graphs in the documents.

Comment: Can you clarify your second sentence? You talk about "emitter" and "Vgs" at the same time, which doesn't make much sense.

Comment: @Damien the main point is that low Vgs = negative tempco and high Vgs = positive tempco. Which is what I said. I may be wrong in the sense that the crossover appears to be substatntially above the subthreshold region. But it is not "the other way around" as you said in your comment. I would go so far as to say that if you try to operate a mosfet as a pass element in a linear regulator you could run into trouble due to the negative tempco. But it is fine when used as a switch as the OP seems to want.